# Spring 3.1 WebApplicationInitializer & Embedded Jetty 8 AnnotationConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-8

I'm trying to create a simple webapp without any XML configuration using Spring 3.1 and an embedded Jetty 8 server.

However, I'm struggling to get Jetty to recognise my implementaton of the Spring *WebApplicationInitializer* interface.

Project structure:

```
src
 +- main
     +- java
     |   +- JettyServer.java
     |   +- Initializer.java
     | 
     +- webapp
         +- web.xml (objective is to remove this - see below).
```

The *Initializer* class above is a simple implementation of *WebApplicationInitializer*:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("onStartup");
    }
}
```

Likewise *JettyServer* is a simple implementation of an embedded Jetty server:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class JettyServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 

        Server server = new Server(8080);

        WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
        webAppContext.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");
        webAppContext.setContextPath("/");
        webAppContext.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] { new AnnotationConfiguration() });
        webAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

        server.setHandler(webAppContext);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

My understanding is that on startup Jetty will use *AnnotationConfiguration* to scan for 
 annotated implementations of *ServletContainerInitializer*; it should find *Initializer* and wire it in...

However, when I start the Jetty server (from within Eclipse) I see the following on the command-line:

```
2012-11-04 16:59:04.552:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.7.v20120910
2012-11-04 16:59:05.046:INFO:/:No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2012-11-04 16:59:05.046:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/Users/duncan/Coding/spring-mvc-embedded-jetty-test/src/main/webapp/}
2012-11-04 16:59:05.117:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

The important bit is this:

```
No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
```

Note that *src/main/java* is defined as a source folder in Eclipse, so should be on the classpath. Also note that the Dynamic Web Module Facet is set to 3.0.

I'm sure there's a simple explanation, but I'm struggling to see the wood for the trees! I suspect the key is with the following line:

```
...
webAppContext.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");
...
```

This makes sense with a 2.5 servlet using web.xml (see below), but what should it be when using *AnnotationConfiguration*?

NB: Everything fires up correctly if I change the Configurations to the following:

```
...
webAppContext.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] { new WebXmlConfiguration() });
...
```

In this case it finds the *web.xml* under *src/main/webapp* and uses it to wire the servlet using *DispatcherServlet* and *AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext* in the usual way (completely bypassing the *WebApplicationInitializer* implementation above).

This feels very much like a classpath problem, but I'm struggling to understand quite how Jetty associates itself with implementations of *WebApplicationInitializer*  - any suggestions would be most appreciated!

For info, I'm using the following:

Spring 3.1.1
  Jetty 8.1.7
  STS 3.1.0

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is that Jetty's `AnnotationConfiguration` class does not scan non-jar resources on the classpath (except under WEB-INF/classes).

It finds my `WebApplicationInitializer`'s if I register a subclass of `AnnotationConfiguration` which overrides `configure(WebAppContext)` to scan the host classpath in addition to the container and web-inf locations.

Most of the sub-class is (sadly) copy-paste from the parent. It includes:

- an extra parse call (`parseHostClassPath`) at the end of the configure method;
- the `parseHostClassPath` method which is largely copy-paste from
  `AnnotationConfiguration`'s `parseWebInfClasses`;
- the `getHostClassPathResource` method which grabs the first non-jar URL
  from the classloader (which, for me at least, is the file url to my
  classpath in eclipse).

I am using slightly different versions of Jetty (8.1.7.v20120910) and Spring (3.1.2_RELEASE), but I imagine the same solution will work.

*Edit: I created a working sample project in github with some modifications (the code below works fine from Eclipse but not when running in a shaded jar) - https://github.com/steveliles/jetty-embedded-spring-mvc-noxml*

In the OP's JettyServer class the necessary change would replace line 15 with:

```
webAppContext.setConfigurations (new Configuration []
{
        new AnnotationConfiguration() 
        {
            @Override
            public void configure(WebAppContext context) throws Exception
            {
                boolean metadataComplete = context.getMetaData().isMetaDataComplete();
                context.addDecorator(new AnnotationDecorator(context));   

                AnnotationParser parser = null;
                if (!metadataComplete)
                {
                    if (context.getServletContext().getEffectiveMajorVersion() >= 3 || context.isConfigurationDiscovered())
                    {
                        parser = createAnnotationParser();
                        parser.registerAnnotationHandler("javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet", new WebServletAnnotationHandler(context));
                        parser.registerAnnotationHandler("javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter", new WebFilterAnnotationHandler(context));
                        parser.registerAnnotationHandler("javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener", new WebListenerAnnotationHandler(context));
                    }
                }

                List<ServletContainerInitializer> nonExcludedInitializers = getNonExcludedInitializers(context);
                parser = registerServletContainerInitializerAnnotationHandlers(context, parser, nonExcludedInitializers);

                if (parser != null)
                {
                    parseContainerPath(context, parser);
                    parseWebInfClasses(context, parser);
                    parseWebInfLib (context, parser);
                    parseHostClassPath(context, parser);
                }                  
            }

            private void parseHostClassPath(final WebAppContext context, AnnotationParser parser) throws Exception
            {
                clearAnnotationList(parser.getAnnotationHandlers());
                Resource resource = getHostClassPathResource(getClass().getClassLoader());                  
                if (resource == null)
                    return;

                parser.parse(resource, new ClassNameResolver()
                {
                    public boolean isExcluded (String name)
                    {           
                        if (context.isSystemClass(name)) return true;                           
                        if (context.isServerClass(name)) return false;
                        return false;
                    }

                    public boolean shouldOverride (String name)
                    {
                        //looking at webapp classpath, found already-parsed class of same name - did it come from system or duplicate in webapp?
                        if (context.isParentLoaderPriority())
                            return false;
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                //TODO - where to set the annotations discovered from WEB-INF/classes?    
                List<DiscoveredAnnotation> annotations = new ArrayList<DiscoveredAnnotation>();
                gatherAnnotations(annotations, parser.getAnnotationHandlers());                 
                context.getMetaData().addDiscoveredAnnotations (annotations);
            }

            private Resource getHostClassPathResource(ClassLoader loader) throws IOException
            {
                if (loader instanceof URLClassLoader)
                {
                    URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)loader).getURLs();
                    for (URL url : urls)
                        if (url.getProtocol().startsWith("file"))
                            return Resource.newResource(url);
                }
                return null;                    
            }
        },
    });
```

*Update*: Jetty 8.1.8 introduces internal changes that are incompatible with the code above. For 8.1.8 the following seems to work:

```
webAppContext.setConfigurations (new Configuration []
    {
        // This is necessary because Jetty out-of-the-box does not scan
        // the classpath of your project in Eclipse, so it doesn't find
        // your WebAppInitializer.
        new AnnotationConfiguration() 
        {
            @Override
            public void configure(WebAppContext context) throws Exception {
                   boolean metadataComplete = context.getMetaData().isMetaDataComplete();
                   context.addDecorator(new AnnotationDecorator(context));   


                   //Even if metadata is complete, we still need to scan for ServletContainerInitializers - if there are any
                   AnnotationParser parser = null;
                   if (!metadataComplete)
                   {
                       //If metadata isn't complete, if this is a servlet 3 webapp or isConfigDiscovered is true, we need to search for annotations
                       if (context.getServletContext().getEffectiveMajorVersion() >= 3 || context.isConfigurationDiscovered())
                       {
                           _discoverableAnnotationHandlers.add(new WebServletAnnotationHandler(context));
                           _discoverableAnnotationHandlers.add(new WebFilterAnnotationHandler(context));
                           _discoverableAnnotationHandlers.add(new WebListenerAnnotationHandler(context));
                       }
                   }

                   //Regardless of metadata, if there are any ServletContainerInitializers with @HandlesTypes, then we need to scan all the
                   //classes so we can call their onStartup() methods correctly
                   createServletContainerInitializerAnnotationHandlers(context, getNonExcludedInitializers(context));

                   if (!_discoverableAnnotationHandlers.isEmpty() || _classInheritanceHandler != null || !_containerInitializerAnnotationHandlers.isEmpty())
                   {           
                       parser = createAnnotationParser();

                       parse(context, parser);

                       for (DiscoverableAnnotationHandler h:_discoverableAnnotationHandlers)
                           context.getMetaData().addDiscoveredAnnotations(((AbstractDiscoverableAnnotationHandler)h).getAnnotationList());      
                   }

            }

            private void parse(final WebAppContext context, AnnotationParser parser) throws Exception
            {                   
                List<Resource> _resources = getResources(getClass().getClassLoader());

                for (Resource _resource : _resources)
                {
                    if (_resource == null)
                        return;

                    parser.clearHandlers();
                    for (DiscoverableAnnotationHandler h:_discoverableAnnotationHandlers)
                    {
                        if (h instanceof AbstractDiscoverableAnnotationHandler)
                            ((AbstractDiscoverableAnnotationHandler)h).setResource(null); //
                    }
                    parser.registerHandlers(_discoverableAnnotationHandlers);
                    parser.registerHandler(_classInheritanceHandler);
                    parser.registerHandlers(_containerInitializerAnnotationHandlers);

                    parser.parse(_resource, 
                                 new ClassNameResolver()
                    {
                        public boolean isExcluded (String name)
                        {
                            if (context.isSystemClass(name)) return true;
                            if (context.isServerClass(name)) return false;
                            return false;
                        }

                        public boolean shouldOverride (String name)
                        {
                            //looking at webapp classpath, found already-parsed class of same name - did it come from system or duplicate in webapp?
                            if (context.isParentLoaderPriority())
                                return false;
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            private List<Resource> getResources(ClassLoader aLoader) throws IOException
            {
                if (aLoader instanceof URLClassLoader)
                {
                    List<Resource> _result = new ArrayList<Resource>();
                    URL[] _urls = ((URLClassLoader)aLoader).getURLs();                      
                    for (URL _url : _urls)
                        _result.add(Resource.newResource(_url));

                    return _result;
                }
                return Collections.emptyList();                 
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This appears to work.  Have you thought about notifying Jetty or sending in a patch?

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer - was exactly what I was looking for. Had a play myself and now have a much clearer understanding of how things work, both from a Jetty and a Spring perspective. Will certainly look to fix within Jetty and submit a patch.

Comment: @Duncan: Was a patch/issue ever filed with Jetty on this?

Comment: @RyanStewart: I can't find one.

Comment: @RyanStewart: I just submitted it: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404176

Answer (score 14):

I was able to resolve in an easier but more limited way by just providing explicitly to the AnnotationConfiguration the implementation class (MyWebApplicationInitializerImpl in this example) that I want to be loaded like this:

```
webAppContext.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] {
    new WebXmlConfiguration(),
    new AnnotationConfiguration() {
        @Override
        public void preConfigure(WebAppContext context) throws Exception {
            MultiMap<String> map = new MultiMap<String>();
            map.add(WebApplicationInitializer.class.getName(), MyWebApplicationInitializerImpl.class.getName());
            context.setAttribute(CLASS_INHERITANCE_MAP, map);
            _classInheritanceHandler = new ClassInheritanceHandler(map);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: In order to get Jersey class scanning to work, I also overrode `WebAppContext.getWebInf()` to always `return newResource("target");` instead of `{resourceBase}/WEB-INF/classes/`.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out that `WebXmlConfiguration` is necessary to allow Jetty to serve resources (like HTML and CSS in `src/main/webapp`). See also `WebAppContext#setResourceBase()`.

Comment: The constructor for ClassInheritanceHandler takes ConcurrentHashMap<String,ConcurrentHashSet<String>> in Jetty 8 and 9? What's required to build this map now? http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/annotations/ClassInheritanceHandler.html

Comment: In Jetty 9 you can use ClassInheritanceMap instead of MultiMap.

Answer (score 6):

Jetty 9.0.1 contains an enhancement which allows for scanning of annotations of non-jar resources (ie classes) on the container classpath. See comment #5 on the following issue for how to use it:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404176#c5

Jan

Comment: Is there an example using a war file? Using .* and .*/classes/.* didn't work :| And I don't really have a jetty_home, since this is embedded jetty.

Answer (score 4):

The code below did the trick in my maven project:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server();
    ServerConnector scc = new ServerConnector(server);
    scc.setPort(Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("jetty.port", "8080")));
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { scc });

    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    context.setServer(server);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setWar("src/main/webapp");
    context.getMetaData().addContainerResource(new FileResource(new File("./target/classes").toURI()));
    context.setConfigurations(new Configuration[]{
            new WebXmlConfiguration(),
            new AnnotationConfiguration()
    });

    server.setHandler(context);

    try {
        System.out.println(">>> STARTING EMBEDDED JETTY SERVER, PRESS ANY KEY TO STOP");
        System.out.println(String.format(">>> open http://localhost:%s/", scc.getPort()));
        server.start();
        while (System.in.available() == 0) {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        server.stop();
        server.join();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(100);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on my testing and this thread http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?127152-WebApplicationInitializer-not-loaded-with-embedded-Jetty I don't think it works at the moment. If you look in AnnotationConfiguration.configure:

```
   parseContainerPath(context, parser);
   // snip comment
   parseWebInfClasses(context, parser);
   parseWebInfLib (context, parser);
```

it seems coupled to a war-like deployment rather than embedded.

Here is an example using Spring MVC and embedded Jetty that might be more useful:

http://www.jamesward.com/2012/08/13/containerless-spring-mvc

It creates the Spring servlet directly rather then relying on annotations.

Comment: Thanks for the jamesward link - good to know how to construct things directly / manually; not knowing this was causing part of my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

To those experiencing this lately, it appears this gets around the issue:

```
@Component
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Autowired
    public WebInitializer(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void onStartup() throws ServletException {
        onStartup(servletContext);
    }

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("onStartup");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect for people using Spring. It looks very clean and gets around all the problems.

Answer (score 2):

To make it work on Jetty 9 set attribute AnnotationConfiguration.CLASS_INHERITANCE_MAP on WebAppContext

```
webAppContext.setAttribute(AnnotationConfiguration.CLASS_INHERITANCE_MAP, createClassMap());
```

And here is how to create this map:

```
private ClassInheritanceMap createClassMap() {
    ClassInheritanceMap classMap = new ClassInheritanceMap();
    ConcurrentHashSet<String> impl = new ConcurrentHashSet<>();
    impl.add(MyWebAppInitializer.class.getName());
    classMap.put(WebApplicationInitializer.class.getName(), impl);
    return classMap;
}
```

I placed that solution on [gitHub](https://github.com/marians27/Playground/blob/master/springRestOnEmbeddedJetty/src/main/java/pl/marian/playground/init/jetty/server/EmbeddedJettyServer.java)

Answer (score 1):

What about just setting the context attribute that tells the scanner which things belong on the container classpath that need to be scanned?

context attribute:
            org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern
            .*/servlet-api-[^/]*.jar$

It is designed to be used with jar names, but you could just match everything.

You'd need to use the WebInfConfiguration as well as the AnnotationConfiguration classes.

cheers
Jan

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get that to work. I set the pattern to .* and I see my classes dir get added to the list of URI's to scan. Unfortunately AnnotationConfiguration uses JarScanner in parseContainerPath, which rejects my classes dir at line 147 because the URI doesn't end in ".jar".

Comment: btw, there's a typo in your profile - I guess you meant webtide.com, not wetide.com?

Answer (score 0):

In our case these lines helped in Jetty startup code:

```
    ClassList cl = Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault(server);
    cl.addBefore("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");
```

Answer (score 0):

Jetty 9 version of "magomarcelo" answer:

```
        context.setConfigurations(
            new org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration[] { new WebXmlConfiguration(), new AnnotationConfiguration() {
                @Override
                public void preConfigure(WebAppContext context) throws Exception {
                    final ClassInheritanceMap map = new ClassInheritanceMap();
                    final ConcurrentHashSet<String> set = new ConcurrentHashSet<>();
                    set.add(MyWebAppInitializer.class.getName());
                    map.put(WebApplicationInitializer.class.getName(), set);
                    context.setAttribute(CLASS_INHERITANCE_MAP, map);
                    _classInheritanceHandler = new ClassInheritanceHandler(map);
                }
            } });
```

Answer (score 0):

For Jetty 9, if you have webjars, the solution provided does not work straight away as those Jars need to be on the classpath and the JAR contents need to be available as resources for your webapp. So, for that to work together with webjars, the config would have to be:

```
context.setExtraClasspath(pathsToWebJarsCommaSeparated);
context.setAttribute(WebInfConfiguration.WEBINF_JAR_PATTERN, ".*\\.jar$");
context.setAttribute(WebInfConfiguration.CONTAINER_JAR_PATTERN, ".*\\.jar$");
context.setConfigurations(
        new org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration[] { 
        new WebInfConfiguration(), new MetaInfConfiguration(),
        new AnnotationConfiguration() {
            @Override
            public void preConfigure(WebAppContext context) throws Exception {
                final ClassInheritanceMap map = new ClassInheritanceMap();
                final ConcurrentHashSet<String> set = new ConcurrentHashSet<>();
                set.add(MyWebAppInitializer.class.getName());
                map.put(WebApplicationInitializer.class.getName(), set);
                context.setAttribute(CLASS_INHERITANCE_MAP, map);
                _classInheritanceHandler = new ClassInheritanceHandler(map);
            }
        } });
```

The order here is important (**WebInfConfiguration has to come before MetaInf**).

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me and does not involve scanning, but uses WebApplicationInitializer class that you provide. Jetty version: 9.2.20

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    InputStream stream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/application.properties");
    properties.load(stream);
    stream.close();
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(properties);

    WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
    webAppContext.setResourceBase("resource");
    webAppContext.setContextPath(properties.getProperty("base.url"));
    webAppContext.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] {
        new WebXmlConfiguration(),
        new AnnotationConfiguration() {
            @Override
            public void preConfigure(WebAppContext context) {
                ClassInheritanceMap map = new ClassInheritanceMap();
                map.put(WebApplicationInitializer.class.getName(), new ConcurrentHashSet<String>() {{
                    add(WebInitializer.class.getName());
                    add(SecurityWebInitializer.class.getName());
                }});
                context.setAttribute(CLASS_INHERITANCE_MAP, map);
                _classInheritanceHandler = new ClassInheritanceHandler(map);
            }
        }
    });

    Server server = new Server(Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("base.port")));
    server.setHandler(webAppContext);
    server.start();
    server.join();
}
}
```

The source (in russian) of this code snippet is here: https://habrahabr.ru/post/255773/

Answer (score 0):

did a simple maven project to demonstrate how it can be done cleanly.

```
    public class Console {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Server server = new Server(8080);

            //Set a handler to handle requests.
            server.setHandler(getWebAppContext());

            //starts to listen at 0.0.0.0:8080
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("server exited with exception", e);
        }
    }

    private static WebAppContext getWebAppContext() {
        final WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();

        //route all requests via this web-app.
        webAppContext.setContextPath("/");

        /*
         * point to location where the jar into which this class gets packaged into resides.
         * this could very well be the target directory in a maven development build.
         */
        webAppContext.setResourceBase("directory_where_the_application_jar_exists");

        //no web inf for us - so let the scanning know about location of our libraries / classes.
        webAppContext.getMetaData().setWebInfClassesDirs(Arrays.asList(webAppContext.getBaseResource()));

        //Scan for annotations (servlet 3+)
        final AnnotationConfiguration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();
        webAppContext.setConfigurations(new Configuration[]{configuration});

        return webAppContext;
    }
}
```

and that's all - the spring WebApplicationInitializer that you use will get detected without explicitly letting jetty server know about the existence of such an app initializer.